# OptionsMenu disappears from fragment on orientation change

Tags: android, fragment, optionmenu, android-optionsmenu

Icons in the option menu work just fine, but when you change orientation by rotating the screen the icons disappear.

```
class SingleRecipeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: SingleRecipeViewModel
    private lateinit var viewModelFactory: SingleRecipeViewModelFactory

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding: FragmentSingleRecipeBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_single_recipe, container, false)
        val args =
            SingleRecipeFragmentArgs.fromBundle(
                requireArguments()
            )

        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application

        viewModelFactory =
            SingleRecipeViewModelFactory(
                args.recipeIndex, application
            )
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,viewModelFactory)
            .get(SingleRecipeViewModel::class.java)

        binding.singleRecipeViewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        viewModel.curRecipe.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            (requireActivity() as MainActivity).toolbar.title = it?.title
        })

        //Toast.makeText(context, "Recipe Number: ${args.recipeIndex}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.single_recipe_menu, menu)

        viewModel.curRecipe.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            val favIconDrawable: Int = if (it!!.favorite) R.drawable.ic_baseline_star_filled_24
            else R.drawable.ic_baseline_star_border_24
            menu.findItem(R.id.favorite).setIcon(favIconDrawable)
        })
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.share -> viewModel.shareSuccess(this.requireActivity())
            R.id.favorite -> viewModel.toggleFavorite()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Here's the menu layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_share_24"
        android:title="Share"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_star_border_24"
        android:title="Share"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

This fragment is launched from another fragment by NavigationUI which passes in the recipeID value. I've tried using setHasOptionsMenu(true) in the onResume of this fragment but it has no effect. Any idea why the optionsMenu is not persistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` in the `onCreate()` method of the MainActivity fixes the problem with the optionsMenu not being persistent. However, this breaks the method I was using to display the title on fragment windows.

The toolbar belongs to the Activity, not the fragment. So when the view is recreated after the orientation change the toolbar is being set to the app title. This doesn't happen when the fragment is first loaded since the title was being set by the fragment's `onCreate()`. So the solution to that was to move the custom titles to `onResume()` of the fragment so that it is reset ever time the view is shown on the screen.

I'm setting the title in the fragment like this, because if I let the Navigation Controller do it using the labels in navigation.xml I get a strange behavior when the fragment loads up where the custom toolbar layout being replace by the new fragment title kind of flashes out to the right.

So the boiled-down code for this solution is:

Fragment:

```
class SingleRecipeFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        /** This will reset your title every time the fragment is redrawn **/
        (requireActivity() as MainActivity).toolbar.title = "Some Custom Title"
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.single_recipe_menu, menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.share -> someMethodYouWantToRun()
            R.id.favorite -> someOtherMethod()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

In `onCreate()` of your Activity, call:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

And here's the menu layout resource file being inflated for the options menu (no change from what's in the question):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_share_24"
        android:title="Share"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_star_border_24"
        android:title="Share"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```